# ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

Note: This is in Oracle 18c

There is one insert happening on temp1 table, then I am calling one of the child stored procedure just after this insert statement. In this stored procedure, I have created PTT(PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE) having this 'temp1' table used as below:

```
Insert into temp1(name, dept, date) values ('A','HR',sysdate);

CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$pgtt
 as
 select dept from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';
```

But I am getting an error:

> ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction

Comment: You probably need to disable parallel DML

Comment: I can't use alter commands in my procedure.

Comment: Also, I noticed that my insert is committing without any commit here and after exception also, it is inserted in DB

Answer (score 3):

It's not allowed to use a table inside CTAS statement if that table has been modiefed in the current transaction.

You may follow the suggestion provided in the error description:

> 32462, 0000, "cannot use an object modified in current transaction"
>   // *Cause:  An object modified in the current transaction was found during the creation of
>   //          in-memory private temporary table using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS).
>   // *Action: **Split the CTAS statement into CREATE TABLE followed by INSERT SELECT**.

```sql
create table temp1 (name varchar2 (32), dept varchar2 (4), hired date);
insert into temp1 values ('A', 'HR', sysdate);

create private temporary table ora$ptt_1 as
    select * from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';

Error report -
ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction
```

At this point please note that, in this special case, the statement `CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY ...` does not issues an implicit `COMMIT` like usually all other DDL statements do. Try it in another session:

```sql
select * from temp1;

no rows selected
```

Back to the first session:

```sql
create private temporary table ora$ptt_1 (name varchar2 (32), dept varchar2 (4), hired date);

Private TEMPORARY created.

insert into ora$ptt_1 
    select * from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';

1 row inserted.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an object that is in the middle of an active transaction as the source for a private temporary table creation. You'll need to end the transaction.

```
SQL> create table temp1 ( name varchar2(10), dept varchar2(10), d date );

Table created.

SQL> Insert into temp1(name, dept, d) values ('A','HR',sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_tab
  2   as
  3   select dept from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';
 select dept from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A'
                  *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction



SQL> Insert into temp1(name, dept, d) values ('A','HR',sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_tab as
  2  select dept from temp1 where dept ='HR' and name ='A';

Table created.
```