# bound variables using oracle parameters

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net

Looking for possibility to bound oracle parameters inside the `execute immediate` statement. But right now facing with issue that I couldn't execute multiple queries inside one statement because of `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-01008: not all variables bound exception`. After researching I've no clue if is possible to do that.

```
        var cmd = new OracleCommand
        {
            CommandText = "begin " +
                          $"  execute immediate 'CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_USERSTMP AS SELECT {string.Join(',', columnNames)} from USERS WHERE 1=0';" +
                          $"  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO ORA$PTT_USERSTMP ({string.Join(',', columnNames)}) VALUES ({string.Join(',', columnNames.Select((c, index) => $":{index + 1}"))})';" +
                          "end;"
        };
        
        cmd.ArrayBindCount = valuesToInsert.First().Count();
        foreach (var value in valuesToInsert)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { OracleDbType = GetType(value), Value = value });
        }
        
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Is there any way to do that or should I implement of using multiple command statement and execute them consistently without 'execute immediate'

**UPDATE 1**
Added `using` statement and it worked but now experiencing another issue, I've added one more statement inside oracle command to update table from temporary, but faced with another issue with: `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction`, the updated statement with commands below:

```
var cmd = new OracleCommand
{
  CommandText = "begin " +
    $"  execute immediate 'CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_USERSTMP AS SELECT {string.Join(',', columnNames)} from USERS WHERE 1=0';" +
    $"  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO ORA$PTT_USERSTMP ({string.Join(',', columnNames)}) VALUES ({string.Join(',', columnNames.Select((c, index) => $":{index + 1}"))})' using {string.Join(',', columnNames.Select((c, index) => $":{index + 1}"))};" +
    $"  execute immediate 'UPDATE USERS2 t1 SET ({string.Join(',', columnNames.Where(s => s != idColumnName).Select(s => "t1." + s))}) = (SELECT {string.Join(',', columnNames.Where(s => s != idColumnName).Select(s => "t2." + s))} FROM ORA$PTT_USERSTMP t2 WHERE t1.{idColumnName} = t2.{idColumnName})';" +
    "  execute immediate 'DROP TABLE ORA$PTT_USERSTMP';" +
    "end;"
};
```

Comment: Check the [USING clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8) of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yes, but how I can combine it with my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ORA-32462 as described [here][1] simple means that the table `USERS` contains *uncommited changes* and you can not use it to create a `PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE` with CTAS

```
create PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_USERSTMP as select * from USERS where 1=0;
```

triggers

```
ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction
```

so you must either `commit` the transaction before the creation if the `PTT` or if not feasible split the creation in `create table` and `insert`

*Simplified example*

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ORA$PTT_USERSTMP (id int, col int)';
  execute immediate 'insert into ORA$PTT_USERSTMP(id,col) values(:1,:2)' using 1, 999;
...
```

Btw you may define the `PTT` with `ON COMMIT DROP DEFINITION` which could eliminate the need of excplicite `DROP`
[1]: [ORA-32462: cannot use an object modified in current transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60933678/ora-32462-cannot-use-an-object-modified-in-current-transaction)